# Content Hub required field not showing message when placed in different column

Tags: content-hub

We are using `Sitecore Content Hub Cloud.` And have set up multiple screens to create a new entity.

For the validation, we set up multiple fields that are required. To display this we have a creation page with multiple columns.

When saving the entity, for example **Product**, the validation works as expected. But not on all the required fields the error message is shown that it is mandatory.

What we want to see:

[image]

But when moving the field to a different column the red border and red error message is no longer shown.

Is there a setting I am missing to achieve this or is it something else?

The field we moved to a different column is **Product families**:

[image]

It shows the `*` that it is required but on save it is not being highlighted.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are facing the same issue.

I have received a message from Sitecore Support with the statement:

```
This issue has been officially logged in the Content Hub product's system.


The bug report is identified by the reference number: MONE-40422.
```

They have not specified a timeline when it will be solved and released.